# Swift Siesta and NSURLSession

Tags: siesta-swift

Looking for a way to still use an NSURLSession but override the siestaNetworkingProvider implementation to return my own NetworkingProvider. This seems impossible however since you can not override protocol extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t override what happens when you pass an `NSURLSession` for the `networking:` param when creating a service — but that is only a convenience anyway.

You can pass your custom networking provider directly:

```
struct MyFancyProvider: NetworkingProvider {
  let session: NSURLSession
  // ...
}

Service(baseURL: "http://whatever", networking: MyFancyProvider(...))
```

(This works because `NetworkingProvider` itself implements `NetworkingProviderConvertible`.)